# Trying to simplify tkz-euclide code

Tags: tkz-euclide

I would like to see if there is a way of condensing this code so I don't need to repeat myself so much, I tried using DrawPolygon but couldn't figure out how to put mark segment or MarkAngles when doing this. Is this possible? The coordinates don't matter just the general appearance, for example I want to do a right triangle, obtuse triangle and then on to hight level polygons.

```
  \documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzDefPoint(-4,0){A}
    \tkzDefPoint(-2.5,2){B}
    \tkzDefPoint(-2,0){C}
    \tkzDefPoint(-1,0){D}
    \tkzDefPoint(0,3){E}
    \tkzDefPoint(1,0){F}
    \tkzDefPoint(2,0){G}
    \tkzDefPoint(3,1.94){H}
    \tkzDefPoint(4,0){I}
        \tkzDrawSegment(A,B)
        \tkzDrawSegment(B,C)
        \tkzDrawSegment(C,A)
        \tkzDrawSegment(D,E)
        \tkzDrawSegment(E,F)
        \tkzDrawSegment(F,D)
        \tkzDrawSegment(G,H)
        \tkzDrawSegment(H,I)
        \tkzDrawSegment(I,G)
             \tkzMarkSegments[mark=|](A,B)
             \tkzMarkSegments[mark=||](B,C)
             \tkzMarkSegments[mark=|||](C,A)
             \tkzMarkSegments[mark=|](D,E E,F)
             \tkzMarkSegments[mark=|](G,H H,I I,G)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code the segment marks are already separate from the lines, so anything wrong with just replacing all the `\tkzDrawSegment` with three `\tkzDrawPolygon`s?

Same for marking angles, that is completely separate from the drawing of the lines, you just specify the names of three points specifying an angle.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzDefPoint(-4,0){A}
    \tkzDefPoint(-2.5,2){B}
    \tkzDefPoint(-2,0){C}
    \tkzDefPoint(-1,0){D}
    \tkzDefPoint(0,3){E}
    \tkzDefPoint(1,0){F}
    \tkzDefPoint(2,0){G}
    \tkzDefPoint(3,1.94){H}
    \tkzDefPoint(4,0){I}

    \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
    \tkzDrawPolygon(D,E,F)
    \tkzDrawPolygon(G,H,I)

    \tkzMarkSegments[mark=|](A,B)
    \tkzMarkSegments[mark=||](B,C)
    \tkzMarkSegments[mark=|||](C,A)
    \tkzMarkSegments[mark=|](D,E E,F)
    \tkzMarkSegments[mark=|](G,H H,I I,G)

    \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.5](A,B,C)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks this will help, I was just wondering if there was a way of making the marks within the DrawPolygon line of code?

Comment: \tkzMarkSegments[mark=||](B,C)
    \tkzMarkSegments[mark=|||](C,A)
    \tkzMarkSegments[mark=|](A,B G,H H,I I,G D,E E,F)

Comment: @PaulA Making marks is independent of the macro `tkzDrawPolygon`